# Read gyro output values with other programming languages

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I have a large quantity of gyro values and I read them through the Arduino serial monitor. I'd like to know how I can use these values in other programming languages (such as C/C++/Java) after the values are read. Are there particular  libraries for the Arduino that could help me in this way?

Comment: See http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1850/how-can-i-reset-the-program-on-an-arduino-uno-while-the-device-isnt-recognised?rq=1. Seems to be much that same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If your Arduino sketch is printing the data as ASCII numeric strings (human-readable), then any language with support for reading and writing to a serial device can interact with your Arduino on the port it is connected to, and collect the gyro data as it is being sent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course you can.

In C/C++ there are different libraries depending on your operating system - that is if you even really need a library to help you at all (in Linux you certainly don't - you just use standard system calls - open, read, etc).

In Java there are a few different ones.  RXTX is a common (though not very good) one.  Personally I ise JSSC(Java Simple Serial Connector) since it contains the JNI files for all the main platforms - you don't have to get the right separate library packages for your specific OS like you do with RXTX.

Then of course there's things like PySerial for Python, Device::SerialPort for Perl, and whatever nonsense Microsoft have created for C# and their .NET stuff.

So in general: pick a language you are comfortable with, then ask Google how to use the serial port in it.